# What would be the best algorithm to find the global optimum of the following non-convex negative log-likelihood function?l

Tags: convex-optimization, maximum-likelihood

I'm working on point process analysis and I'm attempting to fit an [Inverse Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Gaussian_distribution) distribution to a series of inter-event intervals.

My goal is to find the global minimum of the following function

$$
\mathcal{L}(u_{t-n:t}|k,\mathbf{\eta}_t,\theta_t) = -\sum_{i=1}^{n}\eta_i\log p({u}_i|k,\theta_t)\\
$$

by moving in the space of the scaling factor $k$ and the AR coefficients $\theta$.

Here $\eta_i$ are just fixed weighting coefficients, $u_i$ are the target inter-event intervals and $\mu(H_{u_{i-1}},\theta_t)$ is our estimate of the first moment of the IG distribution computed as an AR model

$$
p(u_i|k,\theta_t) = \left[\frac{k}{2\pi\cdot{u_i}^3}\right]^{1/2}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{k\left(u_i-\mu(H_{u_{i-1}},\theta_t)\right)^2}{\mu(H_{u_{i-1}},\theta_t)^2\cdot u_i}}
$$

$$
\mu(H_{u_{i}},\theta_t)=\theta_0+\sum_{j=1}^{p}\theta_ju_{i-j+1}
$$

By looking at the hessian we can see that we can have both positive and negative values, i.e. the function is not convex:

$$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 k}\mathcal{L}(u_{t-n:t}|k,\mathbf{\eta}_t,\theta_t) = {
\sum_{i=1}^{n}
\frac{\eta_i}{2}k^{-2}
}
$$

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial k\partial\theta_{j}}\mathcal{L}(u_{t-n:t}|k,\mathbf{\eta}_t,\theta_t) =
{
\begin{cases}
-\sum_{i=1}^{n}
{\eta_i}
\cdot
\frac{
\left(u_i-\mu_i\right)(u_{i-j})
}
{\mu_i^3}
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ j\neq0\\
-\sum_{i=1}^{n}
{\eta_i}
\cdot
\frac{
\left(u_i-\mu_i\right)(1)
}
{\mu_i^3}
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  j=0
\end{cases}}
$$

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j \partial \theta_q}\mathcal{L}(u_{t-n:t}|k,\mathbf{\eta}_t,\theta_t) =
{
\begin{cases}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\eta_i{k}(u_{i-j})(u_{i-q})\cdot
\left(
\frac{
3\cdot u_i
-
2 \cdot \mu_i
}
{\mu_i^4}
\right)
\ \ \ \ \ \ j\neq0,q\neq0
\\
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\eta_i{k}(1)(u_{i-q})\cdot
\left(
\frac{
3\cdot u_i
-
2 \cdot \mu_i
}
{\mu_i^4}
\right)
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ j=0,q\neq0
\\
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\eta_i{k}(u_{i-j})(1)\cdot
\left(
\frac{
3\cdot u_i
-
2 \cdot \mu_i
}
{\mu_i^4}
\right)
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ j\neq0,q=0
\\
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\eta_i{k}(1)(1)\cdot
\left(
\frac{
3\cdot u_i
-
2 \cdot \mu_i
}
{\mu_i^4}
\right)
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ j=0,q=0
\end{cases}
}
$$

What would be then a good optimisation algorithm which would help me find the global optimum? Would it be ok to use gradient-descent given a decent starting point?

Comment: It is indeed concave in $k$. (But it seems to me you need exactly concave, not convex case for maximization). However my at hand computation showed that it can be non-concave (exactly non-convex either) in any of $\theta$.

Comment: Yes that's actually a negative log likelihood, so I'd like to minimise it

Comment: You should check the Hessian matrix. But as I took the second derivative by individual $\theta$-s, the sign was determined by $u-\mu$. (which seem to take both signs). Maybe I was wrong in my computations. (If you have non-convexity in one component, its enough to say that the function is not convex in general). So just take two time the derivate with respect to some $\theta$.

Comment: Thank you, I checked it and modified the question.

Comment: Here, non-convexity can play bad role in finding global optimum (even with gradient descent). So initial conditions should be taken carefully. However it seems to me , that this function should indeed have one minimum. (I tried to plot it for AR(1), taking some realizations (just from my mind), and it seems to have one minimum). In your place I would hope any algorithm to converge exactly. ))) (If not for scientific article )) ).